# Remove specific commands from Python history

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove specific commands from Python history (`~/.python_history`), however, I'm not succeeding because something keeps getting the commands back at me. I tried writing only commands I want to the file (via Python), then I grepped it to see if deleted commands were there - they weren't. But next time I started the Python shell, grepping confirmed that the commands were there.

What is going on and why is this happening, and how can I circumvent the issue and delete the commands I want?